# PostgreSQL hot standby won't start after deleting WAL files

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have a PostgreSQL 9.1 hot standby server. The WAL files ended up taking up the entire HD so I ended up deleting all the WAP files. How I want to bring the server back up so I ran:

```
/usr/local/pgsql/bin/pg_ctl start  -D /usr/local/pgsql/data
```

The problem is the server never fully starts. I see this follow by non-stop missing WAL files log outputs:

```
server starting
sh-4.1$ LOG:  database system was shut down in recovery at 2013-02-10 03:17:06 UTC
LOG:  entering standby mode
cp: cannot stat `/usr/local/pgsql/wals/0000000100000035000000A4': No such file or directory
LOG:  redo starts at 35/A4943928
LOG:  consistent recovery state reached at 35/A4AE8EB8
LOG:  database system is ready to accept read only connections
LOG:  invalid record length at 35/A4AE8EB8
cp: cannot stat `/usr/local/pgsql/wals/0000000100000035000000A4': No such file or directory
LOG:  streaming replication successfully connected to primary
FATAL:  could not receive data from WAL stream: FATAL:  requested WAL segment 0000000100000035000000A4 has already been removed
```

How can I get the server back?

Comment: The problem - the WAL segment, that is needed to replicate the DB is removed from both primary and replica. Next time you need to clean up the old WAL files - delete all, except few most recent. Or better - set up auto cleanup with `archive_cleanup_command`.

Comment: Thanks, will do that for next time. Suggestions given the situation?

Answer (score 3):

You need to recreate the hot standby server from the dump (or filesystem copy).

Details on how to do that you can find in this manual: [High Availability, Load Balancing, and Replication](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/high-availability.html)

Comment: Not seeing the steps on this page, which part do you suggest?

Comment: @AnApprentice [`Here`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/continuous-archiving.html) you can find detailed manual, how to (re)create standby server.

Comment: Actually none of this is working. Is there a clear answer here?

Comment: Is there a command you can use to similar to resync,reload the slave DB from the master? Thanks

Comment: @AnApprentice All I can give you is the manual page I gave you already.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether required wal's are on the location from which you are restoring for initial restoration before connecting slave to primary host in streaming mode...Above problem can happen due to unavailable wal segment on the location from which you are restoring for initial recovery...If this case is fine then check your restore_command in recovery.conf.